# ember routing and with trying to add a new route not working

Tags: ember.js

I'm just starting Ember and am having problems with a route called posts.images.

In my router, I have:

```
this.resource('posts', function(){
    this.resource('images', { path: ':post_id' });
    this.resource('newpost', { path: 'new' });
    this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
});
```

My Route is:

```
Hex.PostImagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  // same with Hex.PostsImagesRoute
    model: function(params) {
        console.log('alert postimages');
        return Hex.Post.findById(params.post_id);
    }
});
```

and in my template I have:

```
{{#link-to 'posts.images' id}}images{{/link-to}}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Assertion failed: The attempt to link-to route 'posts.images.index' failed. The router did not find 'posts.images.index' in its possible routes: 'loading', 'e
```

I have read the http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/ but am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scroll down a bit:

> NOTE: If you define a resource using this.resource and do not **supply a function**, then the implicit resource.index route is **not created**.

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Comment: thx, the wording on the docs is not so great. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sure, `posts.index` is (implicitly) created since you've passed a function to the post resource in the router.  In this function you've defined the child routes. In order to implicitly create the `posts.images.index` route, you'll have to pass a function to the images resource. Like so: `this.resource('images', { path: ':post_id' }, function(){ //... });` It's a bit silly since the function itself can be left empty..

Comment: You just saved my buddy.